# filter ReportViewer data?

Tags: c#, mysql, reportviewer

I'm trying to make a button to load and filter my ReportViewer by name but the output is data source instance not supplied. Here is my code:

```
private void btnReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String sql = "Select * from practise Where name ='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds);
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("practise", ds.Tables[0]);
            reportViewer2.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            reportViewer2.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                reportViewer2.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                reportViewer2.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
                reportViewer2.RefreshReport();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be simple. Please check that your dataset name in the report is not "DataSet1" by default. Also, make sure that the path for report is correct. Here is a working example:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DemoDB"].ConnectionString))
            {
                 String sql = "Select * from practise Where name ='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adp.Fill(ds);
                ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables[0]);
                reportViewer2.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
              reportViewer2.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    reportViewer2.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                    reportViewer2.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
                    reportViewer2.RefreshReport();
                }
            }
```

I hope that would help someone.